# how to delete all files in a folder using default java package

Tags: java

Am trying to delete all files in a folder and its content. Am using the below code

```
 File deltmpfile = new File(destinationpt);
 deltmpfile.delete();
```

please answer

Comment: What is the question? What's happening with your current code?

Answer (score 9):

You may try to do something like this:

```
for(File f: directory.listFiles()) 
  f.delete();
```

or

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File("directory"));
```

or

```
FileUtils.cleanDirectory(directory);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this here from SO, I'm sorry I forgot the author (credits to him) but if you want to make/customize your own function, do this.

```
    private boolean delete(File pFile) {
        boolean bResult = false;

        if(pFile.exists()) {
            if(pFile.isDirectory()) {
                if(pFile.list().length == 0) {
                    pFile.delete();
                } else {
                    String[] strFiles = pFile.list();

                    for(String strFilename: strFiles) {
                        File fileToDelete = new File(pFile, strFilename);

                        delete(fileToDelete);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                pFile.delete();
            }
        }

        return bResult;
    }
```

Comment: If it's working for you then please choose it as best answer. Thanks.